# do manufacturing or manufacture

Tags: meaning

> But New York changed, and the Navy Yard became known as a place where you could still **do manufacturing** in the city.But New York changed, and the Navy Yard became known as a place where you could still do manufacturing in the city. Film-production companies, fabricators, distillers, and tech firms have all moved in. Here is the all context.
>
> But New York changed, and the Navy Yard became known as a place where you could still **manufacture** in the city.But New York changed, and the Navy Yard became known as a place where you could still do manufacturing in the city. Film-production companies, fabricators, distillers, and tech firms have all moved in. Here is the all context.

But New York changed, and the Navy Yard became known as a place where you could still do manufacturing in the city.
Is there any difference between two sentence in meaning ? Can I use ''do+verb+ing'' instead of verb itself?

Comment: Assuming this is relating to technology hardware/software you would need to give a little context as to what `processing/process` is referring to.

Comment: As I couldn't find rest of the context . I had to change my example . Sorry for this.

Comment: What does manufacturing mean in your context?

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle but important difference between the two constructions.

The first is making it clear that the Navy Yard became known as a place **where manufacturing (of whatever kind) could be carried on**.

The second sentence gives the impression that a direct object is missing after **manufacture**. The reader pauses to ask: **manufacture what?** It can be interpreted in the same fashion as the first, but it is puzzling and not idiomatic.

So stick with the first.